# SQLMembershipProvider source code compatability with latest mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sqlmembershipprovider

I got the source code from here

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/13/442772.aspx

is it compatible with latest ASP.net MVC 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default ASP.Net MVC (including versions 1, 2 and 3) site templates can use Membership Providers including SQLMembershipProvider.

Configuration is via the same methods for standard ASP.Net applications.